# Fetching Location from Android Wear LG Urbane 2nd Edition

Tags: wear-os

I am trying to write wear app. I see that if the phone is not synced with watch through Android Wear app (Eventhough the watch is connected with wifi after disconnecting from Android wear app in phone), Maps app does not pick up the current location.

2. LocationUpdates are NOT fetched when tried as standalone app in both the ways. Below is the code.

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                        .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,locationRequest,this);

```
            LocationServices.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
```

But the above code works perfectly fine with Mobile app.

I am using LG Urbane 2nd edition.

Anyone please help me with this.. LG Urbane 2nd edition says it has GPS then why I am not able to fetch the location details when NOT Synced with phone.

UPDATE:

I found from the following sites that Android wear uses the GPS provider from the phone to get the location updates. Only Sony Smartwatch 3 can fetch the Location updates directly from watch. Is it still the same?

http://www.computerworld.com/article/2919013/android/android-wear-on-wi-fi-using-a-smartwatch-without-a-phone-nearby.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/gps-on-android-wear-devices.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the watch is getting GPS signal? Use an app to test it, or some watches you can test gps in the Dev options, like the sw3.

Answer (score 1):

Update: LG Urbane 2nd edition does appear to have GPS even though it isn't listed in their [official site](https://www.lg.com/us/smart-watches/lg-W200V-lg-watch-urbane-2nd-edition-verizon). Ignore the comments on that page as well that claim it doesn't.

Wear will use a GPS chip if there is one on board. This isn't just the case with the Sony device.

Regarding the [FusedLocationProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi), if you run it on a Wear app, it tries to get the location from the phone b/c it is better on battery among other things.

If the Wear device becomes disconnected from the Phone, then it switches to the GPS on the watch (if it is there). Important, GPS doesn't work inside when on just the Wear device, so you may need to go outside. Also, it may take a moment to get/update the satellite locations the first time you use GPS on the Wear device.

If it isn't, it just returns the last known lat/long position when you were connected to the phone.

There is quite a bit more code involved with the FusedLocationProvider than we see in your snippet.

If you want to see a fully working Wear app using Location (both when connected and not), have a look at the Google sample on GitHub: [SpeedTracker](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-SpeedTracker).

Specifically, look at the [WearableMainActivity.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SpeedTracker/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/speedtracker/WearableMainActivity.java) class. If you have properly connected to the GoogleApiClient AND you have the proper run time permissions for location, this code should work (from SpeedTracker):

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS)
        .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL_MS);

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
        .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                if (status.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully requested location updates");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG,
                            "Failed in requesting location updates, "
                                    + "status code: "
                                    + status.getStatusCode() + ", message: " + status
                                    .getStatusMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: LG Urbane 2nd Edition watch has in-built GPS. Since I am testing inside the building I was not able to fetch the location details. I took the watch outside where GPS signal is there, I was able to fetch current location latitude and longitude without phone. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned GPS doesn't work inside. I saw that with Sony watch. Cool, I am glad you got it to work. I will revise my answer to help others.